# String operation with array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, string

I have a array of strings like the example below

`["i.was.wen.the.coding", "i.am.wen.to", "i.am.new", "i.am", "i"]`

u can see all sentence in array can be split by `.` and I need to make logical algo pattern to create a sentence meaningful by taking the array in reverse and stitch back the words at the end. if u read it from last, as `i.am.new.to.coding` taking last spit value from each sentence makes a meaningful sentence at last. am trying to create such a code in javascript or jquery and am stuck with this for more than a day. since it is so tricky.

any script experts plz help to make this. I appreciate your help. TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems straight forward, reverse the array, map it returning the last part after the period, then join with spaces

```js
var arr = ["i.was.wen.the.coding", "i.am.wen.to", "i.am.new", "i.am", "i"];

var s = arr.reverse().map(function(x) {
    return x.split('.').pop();
}).join(' ');

document.body.innerHTML = s;
```

Comment: It works like charm for any input and any delimiter I actually needed. Hats off for ur valuable help. and I never thought it ll done in such a simple and understandable code. :) Thanks a lot adeneo

Answer (score 2):

```js
var a = ["i.was.wen.the.coding", "i.am.wen.to", "i.am.new", "i.am", "i"];

var s = a.reduceRight(function(x,y){
    return x + '.' + y.split('.').pop();
});

document.body.textContent = s;
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
var array = ["i.was.wen.the.coding", "i.am.wen.to", "i.am.new", "i.am", "i"]
var b = [];
for(i=array.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    var a = array[i].split('.').pop()
    b += " "+a
    alert(a)
}
alert(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
arr = ["i.was.wen.the.coding", "i.am.wen.to", "i.am.new", "i.am", "i"];
arr = arr.reverse();
str = '';
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    data = arr[i].split('.');
    len = data.length;
    str = str + data[len-1] + " ";
}
console.log(str);
```